# PHP: creating arrays with year numbers from 1980 till now

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having the following array …

```
'type' => 'select',
    'options' => array(
        array('name' => '1980', 'value' => '1980'),
        array('name' => '1981', 'value' => '1982'),
        array('name' => '1983', 'value' => '1983'),
        …
        …
        array('name' => '2011', 'value' => '2011'),
        array('name' => '2012', 'value' => '2012'),
    )
```

Any idea how to write that thing "dynamically" so that the `options` array is filled with the year numbers from 1980 till 2012 automatically?

```
'type' => 'select',
    'options' => array(
        // create array's from 1980 till date('Y') automatically
    )
```

Right now I hardcoded all those lines and I guess this could be done a lot more efficiently and simpler.

Thank you in advance,
Matt

Comment: Might I suggest reading up on basic programming techniques? Loops are the kinda thing you should cover very early on to solve these kinda of issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate it on the fly when you assign it to the array:

```
$array = array('type' => 'select',
    'options' => array_map(function($year) {
            return array('name' => $year, 'value' => $year);
        }, range(1980, 2012))
);
```

If you move away the fuzz, you can see it is actually making use of the [`range`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/range) function and of the [`array_map`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/array_map) function. So nothing really fancy.

Answer (score 6):

```
$years = array();    
for ($y = 1980, $now = date('Y'); $y <= $now; ++$y) {
    $years[$y] = array('name' => $y, 'value' => $y);
}
```